API Gateway - how to properly deal with SNYK scan security issues?
I have an api gateway post endpoint which is restricted to be accessed for a certain IP address using this method.
my organisation snyk security scan has come up with some issues listed below.
I wanted to know even though I have restricted my IP address, would it be unwise to ignore these issues?
the following security issues:
SNYK-CC-00757 - API Gateway must be protected by AWS WAF
SNYK-CC-00250 - API Gateway allows anonymous access
SNYK-CC-00752 - IAM policy allows privilege escalation
